# Subordinate matrix norm inequality in research paper where authors replace $||A||_{op}^2$ with $||A^TA||_{op}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I'm perusing [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0546). In page 8, I came across this:

[image]

My question is about equation 45. Also in this question I don't care about neither $u$ nor $M$, I mentioned them just to give some context.

In short my problem is:

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

$\|.\|$ is the euclidean vector norm, $\|.\|_{op}$ is a matrix norm defined as:
$$\|A\|_{op} = \max_x \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$$

So I have: $|y^TAx| \leq \|y\|\space\|A\|_{op}\|x\|$. As long as I have an inequality with the absolute value of something, it is the same as $y^TAx \leq \|y\|\space\|A\|_{op}\|x\|$

Now I will multiply both sides by 2 and multiply the left side by:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\tau}}{\sqrt{\tau}}\frac{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{4}}}{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$

Then I get:
$$2y^TAx \leq\ 2
\frac{\|A\|_{op} \|y\| \sqrt{\tau}} 
{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\frac{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{4}} \|x\| } 
{\sqrt{\tau}}$$

using $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$:
$$2y^TAx \leq\
\frac{\|A\|^2_{op} \tau} 
{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{2}}} \|y\|^2 +
\frac{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{2}} } 
{\tau} \|x\|^2 $$

In equation 45, the term $\|A\|^2_{op}$ doesn't appeard, it is replaced by $\|A^TA\|_{op}$. I know that $\|A\|^2_{op} \geq \|A^TA\|_{op}$, so I don't know why the authors make this replacement. In the paper, they say that $A$ is any matrix with no special properties.

The next line comes from doing:
$$(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{2}}z = \frac{\|A^TA\|_{op} \tau} 
{(\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$\tau\sigma \|A^TA\|_{op} z = \|A^TA\|_{op} \tau$$
$$z = \frac{1}{\sigma}$$

Why do authors replace $\|A\|_{op}^2$ with $\|A^TA\|_{op}$ in equation 45? With this replacement the inequalities don't necessarily hold. Is there a property I am missing?

Comment: Hint: Use `\|` instead of `||` to get better-looking double bars ($\|A\|$ instead of $||A||$).

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the hint, I didn't know about it. I'll use it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use $\langle x,y\rangle$ to denote the usual inner product $y^*x$.

It is always true that $$\|A\|^2_{op}=\|A^*A\|_{op},$$ where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint (the conjugate transpose, so just the transpose if $A$ is real). This is very easy to prove. The reverse inequality from the one you mention is the easy one: 
\begin{align}
\|A\|^2&=\max\{ \|Ax\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}=\max\{\langle Ax,Ax\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&=\max\{\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&\leq \|A^*A\|,
\end{align}
where the inequality is simply Cauchy-Schwarz and definition of the operator norm. Now, from the above inequality, you have 
$$
\|A\|^2\leq\|A^*A\|\leq\|A^*\|\,\|A\|. 
$$
So, for nonzero $A$ (the zero case is trivial) you have $\|A\|\leq\|A^*\|$. Apply the above to $A^*$, to get $\|A^*\|\leq\|A^{**}\|=\|A\|$, so $\|A^*\|=\|A\|$. If you now go back to the inequalities we had, 
$$
\|A\|^2\leq\|A^*A\|\leq\|A^*\|\,\|A\|=\|A\|^2. 
$$
So $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|$.